# Woocommerce API Put request returning 500 error if too much data

Tags: php, api, apache, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to batch update products on woocommerce.

If I submit an update for example 10 products I get a 500 error:

```
"</pre><br><br><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
    <title>500 &mdash; Internal Sever Error</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Sorry, something went wrong. Internal Server Error"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {font-size:14px; color:#777777; font-family:arial; text-align:center;}
        h1 {font-size:180px; color:#99A7AF; margin: 70px 0 0 0;}
        h2 {color: #DE6C5D; font-family: arial; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; margin: -3px 0 39px;}
        p {width:320px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; margin-top: 30px }
        div {width:320px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
        a:link {color: #34536A;}
        a:visited {color: #34536A;}
        a:active {color: #34536A;}
        a:hover {color: #34536A;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p><a href="http://website.co.nz/">website.co.nz</a></p>

    <h1>500</h1>
    <h2>Internal Server Error</h2>
    <div>
        Sorry, something went wrong :(
    </div>
</body>"
```

However If I batch update only a couple of products it works perfectly.

I assume I need to increase something maybe in a apache config file so the browser can accept more information.

Which config file should be updated, and what needs to be updated?

Many thanks,

Comment: As http 500 errors are `Internal Server Errors` you should investigate your server **error logs** and add the output. That would give us a good insight!